Background color of content in webpage does not extend when page is scrolled
I have a webpage with a sticky header and footer.  Inside the main body I have a page and inside the page is content.  I want to have a scrollbar on the page.  I have added some text inside the content but when I scroll down the background color of the content only extends the height of the viewport.  The text continues to be visible upon scrolling but not the background color.  The content is green.


/******************************************************************************/
/*                                  MAIN BODY                                 */
/******************************************************************************/
    :root {
        --background-color: #fbedcf;
        --primary-color: #77037B;
        --label-color: #210062;
        --secondary-color: #009FBD;
        --white-color: #FFFFFF;
        --black-color: #000000;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        /*NOTE:  Bootstrap uses base font size of 16px  Use percentages of this to change size. */
        font-family: Roboto serif;
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .page {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: solid 50px transparent;
        border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: var(--background-color);
    }

    .content {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
    }
    p {
        color: var(--label-color);
    }

    /******************************************************************************/
/*                                    HEADER                                 */             
/****************************************************************************/
    header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 98;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        text-align: center;
    }

    #header-title {
        margin: auto;
        font-family: Roboto, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color: var(--background-color);
        letter-spacing: 0.03em;
        font-size: 140%;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    /********************************************************************/
    /*                           FOOTER                                */
    /*******************************************************************/
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        margin-top: auto;
        background-color: var(--background-color);
        color: var(--black-color);
    }

    .footer-label {
        color:var(--primary-color);
        font-size: 70%;
        line-height: 24px;
    }

    #line-div {
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        margin-right: 24px;
    }

    #copywrite-div {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background-color: pink;
    }
    #copywrite-label-div {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .footer-button {
        border: none;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-left: 1px solid #999;
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    .footer-advertisement {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: var(--white-color);
    }

    .footer-ad-rectangle {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 70%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height:50px;
        background-color: var(--white-color);
    }
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
              integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-------------------------------------- START -------------------------->
    <header>
        <div id="header-title">THIS IS THE HEADER</div>
    </header>

    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <p>THIS IS THE BEGINNING</p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
          
             <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                THE END THE END
            </p>

        </div>  <!-- end content -->

    </div> <!-- end page -->

    <footer>
        <div id="copywrite-div">
            <div id="copywrite-label-div">
                <div class="footer-label">Copyright &copy; 2024 - Yogi Bear</div>
            </div>
            <button class="footer-button" id="close-footer-ad-button">X</button>
        </div>

        <div id="line-div"></div>

        <div class="footer-advertisement" id="footer-ad">
            <div class="line-div"></div>
            <div class="footer-ad-rectangle"> Advertisement</div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <!--------------------------------------- END ------------------------------>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>




The Problem and How to Fix it
This is the CSS for your .content div.
.content {
    /* height: 100%; remove this. */
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

The height: 100%; makes the .content div have a height of only 100%, which in this case is the height of screen. Hence it can't stretch itself till, the end of the text inside it. So removing it will give you want you wanted.
The fixed snippet


/******************************************************************************/
/*                                  MAIN BODY                                 */
/******************************************************************************/
    :root {
        --background-color: #fbedcf;
        --primary-color: #77037B;
        --label-color: #210062;
        --secondary-color: #009FBD;
        --white-color: #FFFFFF;
        --black-color: #000000;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        /*NOTE:  Bootstrap uses base font size of 16px  Use percentages of this to change size. */
        font-family: Roboto serif;
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .page {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: solid 50px transparent;
        border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: var(--background-color);
    }

    .content {
        background-color: green;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
    }
    p {
        color: var(--label-color);
    }

    /******************************************************************************/
/*                                    HEADER                                 */             
/****************************************************************************/
    header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 98;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        text-align: center;
    }

    #header-title {
        margin: auto;
        font-family: Roboto, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color: var(--background-color);
        letter-spacing: 0.03em;
        font-size: 140%;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    /********************************************************************/
    /*                           FOOTER                                */
    /*******************************************************************/
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        margin-top: auto;
        background-color: var(--background-color);
        color: var(--black-color);
    }

    .footer-label {
        color:var(--primary-color);
        font-size: 70%;
        line-height: 24px;
    }

    #line-div {
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        margin-right: 24px;
    }

    #copywrite-div {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background-color: pink;
    }
    #copywrite-label-div {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .footer-button {
        border: none;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-left: 1px solid #999;
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    .footer-advertisement {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: var(--white-color);
    }

    .footer-ad-rectangle {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 70%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height:50px;
        background-color: var(--white-color);
    }
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
              integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-------------------------------------- START -------------------------->
    <header>
        <div id="header-title">THIS IS THE HEADER</div>
    </header>

    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <p>THIS IS THE BEGINNING</p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
          
             <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </p>
            <p>
                THE END THE END
            </p>

        </div>  <!-- end content -->

    </div> <!-- end page -->

    <footer>
        <div id="copywrite-div">
            <div id="copywrite-label-div">
                <div class="footer-label">Copyright &copy; 2024 - Yogi Bear</div>
            </div>
            <button class="footer-button" id="close-footer-ad-button">X</button>
        </div>

        <div id="line-div"></div>

        <div class="footer-advertisement" id="footer-ad">
            <div class="line-div"></div>
            <div class="footer-ad-rectangle"> Advertisement</div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <!--------------------------------------- END ------------------------------>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>



Happy coding! :)

Thank you.  Both answers received today work.  What I don't understand is why the text was shown when it was inside the content.  It was only the background color that wasn't showing.  If the content was only the same height as the viewheight, shouldn't the text only be displayed to this height as well?

@LornafromPerth Well, the .content div had a set height, that is, 100% or the height of its parent (.page). The text inside it is larger than that, but as it still has to render it entirely, it overflows the height given by its parent element (.content). But if you wanted it to be displayed only up to the height of the parent element (.content), you can put this css attribute in to the .content div: overflow: none, which simply states that none of the children elements of .content should overflow outside the boundaries of the element.

Also I would recommend going through this link about the overflow CSS property: overflow - CSS Property

@LornafromPerth You're welcome. Also I would like remind that you should mark a answer, which is the most helpful to you, as accepted.

The height: 100% fills 100% of parent's height, which is 100vh. To make it equal to children height use height: fit-content or height: max-content.
